# Cannot find symbol error..?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class CustomerTest
{

  public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String message = "";
        ArrayList<Customer> cList;

        ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();

        Customer c1 = new Customer ("Jones", new Address("Cooper","Arlington", "Texas", 76019), 12345);
        Customer c2 = new Customer ("Smith", new Address("Bowen","Arlington", "Texas", 76006), 65489);
        Customer c3 = new Customer ("willis", new Address("Bowen","Arlington", "Texas",75550), 27589);

                c1.setCType(Customer.CustomerType.STUDENT);
                c2.setCType(Customer.CustomerType.FACULTY);
                c3.setCType(Customer.CustomerType.GOVERNMENT);




        customerList.add(c1);
        customerList.add(c2);
                customerList.add(c3);


                Course co1 = new Course ("Java 1","Davis", 125.00, new Date(1,1,2015), new Date(1,15,2015));
                Course co2 = new Course ("Java 2","Jones", 125.00, new Date(1,1,2015), new Date(1,15,2015));
        Course co3 = new Course ("InClassCourse","PHOTOGRAPHY", 75.00, new Date(2,5,2015), new Date(3,2,2015));


         for (Customer c: customerList)
         {

          {
            message += c.creatInvoice() + "\n" + c.createInvoice();
          }
         }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    } 
}
```

I'm it at

```
message += c.creatInvoice() + "\n" + c.createInvoice();
```

I've been working on this for hours and can't figure out what it wants. Do I need to declare it in the class? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `creatInvoice` -> `createInvoice`.

Comment: What's this about an error? Are you getting an error? (Then say so, and say exactly what the error says)

Answer (score 0):

You posed the error right in your recap.

```
`creatInvoice()`
```

Should be

```
`createInvoice()`
```

You are getting `symbol not found` because the compiler does not know what `creatInvoice` is.

Comment: I changed the `createInvoice();`

Comment: but Now I'm getting this error `run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Customer.getCustomerList
 at CustomerTest.main(CustomerTest.java:40)
Java Result: 1`